# Tabs don't initialize inside collapsible body in materialize

Tags: tabs, initialization, materialize, jquery-mobile-collapsible

The indicator line is not showing up on the active tab on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize it on the onOpen callback in collapsible.

`$('body .collapsible').collapsible({onOpen: function(){ $('ul.tabs').tabs() } })`